# Extracting only files that match specific number from many compressed files

Tags: windows-xp, archiving, extract, rar, winrar

I have over 500 rar files with lots of compressed ppt files in one directory. I would like to search each archive if archive has file prj_09hr23 in name and ppt extension.
What program should I use to extract only ppt files with prj_09hr23 in file name?

I have Windows XP Pro SP3 and I have 7z installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinRAR has such a function.

1. Install WinRAR, I got it from http://www.winrar.nl/ it has an English version available.
2. Start WinRAR and browse to the folder that contains all your archives.
3. List item go to `Extra` -> `Search Files` (Or press F3)
4. Search in current directory and set your search parameters. It will now search for any matches in your archives.
5. When matches have been found, select the files you want and click "Extract".